# How to save data and load into Shiny app from R.Data File

Tags: r, shiny, rdata

I'm creating DT Table with observe() with value can be updated when user fills the table as below picture :

[image]

my goal is I would like to save the updated data to R.Data when clicked the **Do Save Data Button**,
and if close my shiny application and if I opened again I can call again the information that I have been input before.

The issue is I don't know how to load the data
[image]
[image]

Any solution or suggestion is really helpful, below are my script

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebarpanel")),
  dashboardBody(shinyjs::useShinyjs(), uiOutput("body"))
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$sidebarpanel <- renderUI({
    sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("test2", tabName = "T2", icon = icon("th")),
        actionButton("doSave", "Do Save Data"),
        actionButton("doLoad", "Do Load Data")
      )
    })
  
  output$body <- renderUI({
        tabItems(
        
        tabItem(tabName ="T2", class = "active",
                fluidRow(
                  box(width = 12, title = "DT Result", status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE,
                      collapsible = TRUE,
                      splitLayout(
                        box(width = 12, title = "Content A", status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                            collapsible = TRUE, dataTableOutput('content_SC_RSR'))))
                  
                )))
    })
  
  
  ##################################### TABLE RESULT 1 ##################################################
  vc <- 'value'
  SC_RSR <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  
  data_SC_RSR = data.frame(
    KSF = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
    SCORE = c(NA, NA, NA)
    
  )
  
  SC_RSR_Data <- reactive ({
    data_SC_RSR
  })
  
  observe({
    SC_RSR$data <- SC_RSR_Data()
    
  })
  
  output$content_SC_RSR <-  DT::renderDataTable({
    SC_RSR$data %>%
      datatable(editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = c(0,1))), options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$content_SC_RSR_cell_edit, {
    info = input$content_SC_RSR_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = as.numeric(info$value)
    
    SC_RSR$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v, SC_RSR$data$data[i, j])
    
  })
  
  
  
  #Saving data
  observeEvent(input$doSave, {
    save(SC_RSR,  file = "data.RData")
    Save_done <- showNotification(paste("Message", "Data Has been saved"), duration = NULL)
  })
  
  #Load data
  observeEvent(input$doLoad, {
    SC_RSR <- load("data.RData")
    Load_done <- showNotification(paste("Message", "Data Has been loaded"), duration = NULL)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

UPDATE

I already found the solution, I add some solutions as below :

```
#Saving data
  observeEvent(input$doSave, {
    savedata <<- SC_RSR$data
    save(savedata,  file = "data.RData")
    Save_done <- showNotification(paste("Message", "Data Has been saved"), duration = NULL)
  })
  
  #Load data
  observeEvent(input$doLoad, {
    load("data.RData")
    SC_RSR$data <- savedata
    Load_done <- showNotification(paste("Message", "Data Has been loaded"), duration = NULL)
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot yet make persistent data storage on shiny servers run on shinyapps.io. The solution is to write and read to a cloud drive like dropbox. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html

edit: if you are just local or on your own server, you can use save() and load() for RData files.

Comment: thanks a lot but i'm not run it on Shinyapps.io i run it on my local host

Comment: if you are just local or on your own server, you can use save() and load() for RData files.